# Print unicode glyph together with its codepoint

Tags: pdftex, unicode

Is it possible to define a macro, call it `charwithcodepoint`, such that

```
\charwithcodepoint{A}
```

emits an equivalent of

```
\texttt{A} (U+0041)
```

And similar for other codepoints as well. If not, can I do the opposite, `codepointwithchar` so

```
\codepointwithchar{U+0041}
```

emits an equivalent to

```
\texttt{A} (U+0041)
```

I would like to do so in order to document a parser. Is there a package that support this?

The engine `pdftex` and the input file is UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New version that takes a single UTF-8 character or a single ASCII letter command sequence such as `\#`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D400}{\textbf{\textrm{A}}}% for demo only

% code mostly from the 2015/10/01 latex release inputenc)

\makeatletter
\def\charwithcodepointb#1{%
\texttt{#1}
(%
U+%
\expandafter\UTFviii@hexnumber\expandafter{%
                     \the\numexpr\expandafter\decode@UTFviii\detokenize{#1}\relax})%
}


\gdef\decode@UTFviii#1\relax{%
  \expandafter\UTFviii@cleanup
    \the\numexpr\dec@de@UTFviii#1\relax)))))\@empty}
\gdef\UTFviii@cleanup#1)#2\@empty{#1}
\def\d@c@de@UTFviii#1{%
\dec@de@UTFviii{#1}}
\gdef\dec@de@UTFviii#1{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
  \ifnum`#1>"EF 
    ((((`#1-"F0)%
  \else
    \ifnum`#1>"DF 
      (((`#1-"E0)%
    \else
      \ifnum`#1>"BF 
        ((`#1-"C0)%
      \else
        \ifnum`#1>"7F 
        )*64+(`#1-"80)%
        \else
        +`#1 %
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\dec@de@UTFviii
\fi}
\gdef\UTFviii@hexnumber#1{%
\ifnum#1<"10 0\fi
\ifnum#1<"100 0\fi
\ifnum#1<"1000 0\fi
\UTFviii@hexnumb@r{#1}}
\gdef\UTFviii@hexnumb@r#1{%
\ifnum#1>15 %
\expandafter\UTFviii@hexnumb@r\expandafter{\the\numexpr(#1-8)/16\relax}%
\fi
\UTFviii@hexdigit{\numexpr#1\ifnum#1>0-((#1-8)/16)*16\fi\relax}%
}
\gdef\UTFviii@hexdigit#1{\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax
  0\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or6\or7\or8\or9\or
  A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\fi}



\def\charwithcodepoint#1{%
\ifcat\relax\noexpand#1%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\charwithcodepointb\expandafter\@gobble\string#1
\else
\charwithcodepointb{#1}%
\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\charwithcodepoint{A}

\charwithcodepoint{Á}

\charwithcodepoint{}


\charwithcodepoint{\A}

\charwithcodepoint{\\}

\charwithcodepoint{\#}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be worth to put into a package. Interestingly `\textbackslash` is 0x5cd rather than 0x5c

Comment: @user877329 I just copied it from inputenc package as I note in the comment in the code.

Comment: How can I fix `#` and `\\`, because these are wrong (And my syntax use them).

Comment: @user877329 `\textbackslash` ?? The command has to be given a single character, you can not give it a command sequence.

Comment: `\expandafter\charwithcodepoint\string#` and `\makeatletter\expandafter\charwithcodepoint\@backslashchar` probably work

Comment: But a I cannot type either # or `\\` directly.

Comment: @user877329 I don't really understand the issue, either you are taking arbitrary input and so have presumably already made `#` safe or you just want that specific instance in which case you do not need a command at all and can just use `\textt{\#} (U+0023)`

Comment: Can the macro be made verbatim somehow? For the command to be useful, *all* ascii character must work. So either, with the escaped version should work out of the box (preferred) or fiddling with catcodes (bad, since this is one of the dark corners of TeX). It is most likely that other characters are not needed (if you are not using strange characters in your language).

Comment: @user877329  If you only want the ascii range you can discard 90% of the above code:-)

Comment: @user877329 easiest if you could take single letter command names as arguments such as `\#`, `\\ `, `\A`, rather than just the character, then catcodes are not involved. Would that work for you?

Comment: @DavidCarlsle Yes, it would. But what about ( and ). \\( begins inline math mode...

Comment: @user877329 answer update